# Fill Kendo UI Grid

Tags: user-interface, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, grid

`DataSourceResult` does not contain a definition for `ToDataSourceResult` and the best extension method overload `QueryableExtensions.ToDataSourceResult(DataTable, DataSourceRequest)` requires a receiver of type `DataTable`

```
var results = db.Accounts.ToDataSourceResult(
    request, 
    o => new {
        ID = o.ID,
        AccCode = o.AccCode,
        AccName = o.AccName,
        Phone = o.Phone,
        Email = o.Email,
        DateBirth = o.DateBirth,
        Address = o.Address,
        Type = o.Type
    }
);

return Json(results.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: @( Html.Kendo().Grid<POS.Models.AccountsViewModel>()
               .Name("client")

Comment: public class AccountsViewModel
    {

       

        public long ID { get; set; }

        public long? AccCode { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string AccName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Phone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string DateBirth { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public int? OfferID { get; set; }

        public int? Type { get; set; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your results var is *already* a DataSourceResult so you don't have to do it again in the Json().